# Frequent file corruption but HDD passes all tests

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ntfs, smart

My laptop (MSI GL63-8RD) has a 1 TB HDD with NTFS partitions. OS is on SSD.

My code files keep on getting garbage data in them or they just vanish.

I ran `chkdsk /f /r /x` on the volume, which deletes some of the files, restores few in the found directory. It also reports 8KB bad sectors.

Files from my other volumes also keep on vanishing. chkdsk deletes few, restored few but doesnt report any bad sectors.

Its a seagate HDD so I used the SeaTools to perform the following tests:

1. SMART
2. Short Drive Self Test
3. Short Generic
4. Long Generic

It passed all of the above tests. I have been doing chkdsk for a while but the number of bad sectors according to it are not increasing.

Is this a windows issue or my HDD is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Change the SATA cable.
Clean the sockets with contact cleaner then ensure the new cable has no tension on it once installed. SATA cables hate to be pulled out of square.

Comment: I just edited the question. I have a laptop and the last time I opened it, it was just a slot.

Comment: Then it could be as Keltari mentions, the controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my SSD.  I had occasional file corruption and once or twice a month, the PC would not boot.  All the drive tests showed the drive as perfectly operational.  I eventually swapped the drive with another one.  Since the time between faults was long, it took a while to notice I had the same issue on the new drive.  This pointed to a different problem, other than the drives.  I tried different SATA cables, but it still happened.  This left the SATA controller itself.  I ordered a new PCIe SATA controller and everything has worked since.  As it turns out, the onboard SATA controller was failing.

Comment: Its a laptop, I'm not sure if I'll have those options

Comment: well, you can still test with another drive.  If the replacement drive still exhibits the same problem, then its likely a motherboard/sata controller issue.

Comment: ok, is it possible that the HDD itself is failing even if it passes all those tests?

Comment: @DushyantBangal anything is possible